# Filter with OR in neomodel

Tags: django, python-3.x, neo4j, neomodel

Recently I start to useing neo4j and neomodel and now I need to filter 2 parameters with OR in neomodel. I searched in document and codes but couldn't find anything about it. In django model there is a Q object to handle OR in queries. How can handle OR query in neomodel?
I have to get query params from http request and response to it. Neomodel handle AND but I have no idea for handling queries with OR. Is there any way to handle it with out using cypher mannualy?

Comment: I made some changes to solve this issue. Visit https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/pull/336

Comment: This feature added to neomodel: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/blob/master/doc/source/queries.rst#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 1):

In version **neomodel 3.3.4**(3)  exists Q support.

```
Model.nodes.filter(Q(Q(a) | Q(b)) & Q(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a double-underscore prefixed `in` operator as described in the [advanced queries section](http://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queries.html) of the docs. So it's like `title__in`

Comment: There is not a such thing for OR. I need something like this **created>=30 OR updated>=30**. How can I do this? I look at codes and in build_where_stmt function AND is fixed, I think for now there is no support for OR in neomodel query.